# Ubuntu installation wrongly scans my disk

Tags: partitioning, windows

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Doing so, Ubuntu thinks I already have Debian installed which is not the case and it doesn't detect my Windows installation. It also thinks my disk is 1Tb but it's actually 500Gb.

By fear of wiping my Windows partition, I stopped the installation. Any thoughts on the situation?

Comment: Thoughts? The Ubuntu installer was drunk or you were.

Comment: That's really weird, can you share a screenshot of that while using the Ubuntu installer, and then when you're on Windows?

Comment: After trying again, I realized the 1Tb disk Ubuntu was an external drive. Unfortunately, I want to install Ubuntu on my internal drive but [it doesn't seem to be recognized by the installer.](https://i.imgur.com/MTQwssP.jpg) Maybe it has something to do with the fact that my internal disk is MBR formated? (That's really a guess..)

Comment: Did you disconnect all external drives except for the Ubuntu Live USB?

Comment: Yes. Nothing plugged in except the Ubuntu Live USB.